# .Net web services over SSL?

Tags: c#, web-services

i just changed my services to work strictly over SSL and i am getting the following error:{"The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.\r\nParameter name: via"}

I didn't know i couldn't just change protocols, from what i have seen from googling around this may be a change in the web config but i don't know where.  Here is my current web config. Any help is appreciated!:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="microsoft.web.services3" type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Configuration.WebServicesConfiguration, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </configSections>
  <microsoft.web.services3>  
    <messaging>
      <maxMessageLength value="-1"/>
      <mtom serverMode="always"/>
      <maxMessageLength value="2147483647"/>
    </messaging>
  </microsoft.web.services3>
  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web> 
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
    <httpHandlers>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.net>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5551

Comment: I appreciate your feedback but that answer seems to be for certificates that are not publicly signed.  Mine is and i see no errors when i go to the address in a web browser, however it still gives this error when calling it by code.

Comment: Also this is .net 4.0 and IIS 7.5.

Comment: If it's .NET 4 how come you are using web service and not WCF? Or did I misread that?